# Unhandled exception on trying to create JAXBContext (Jaxb 2.0)

Tags: java, jaxb2

I am trying to get the code past this line:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("foo.bar.package");
```

It throws an exception - heres the stack trace - any ideas folks?

```
SEVERE: Unhandled exception or error intercepted
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:172)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:25)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:41)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:97)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:44)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:320)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:198)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:76)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:55)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:132)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:286)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:358)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:323)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:244)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a JAR file, most likely, `activation.jar` in your application.  You must have this JAR available when you compile (unless it is invoked from a 3rd party library you are using).  Ensure that this JAR is available in the correct location for the application to make use of it.

Comment: You shining star of brilliance!!!  Obviously documentation I have not managed to read..